# How does the order of random variables matter?

Tags: random-variables

Consider two random variables $X_1, X_2$ on sample space $\Omega$.

Let $P_1, P_2$ are two probability distributions over $X_1, X_2$ for which only order differ. I mean $P_1 (X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2)$ and $P_2 (X_2=x_2, X_1=x_1)$ and all the values are probability values are same.

My doubt in first step is that how to [order of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) matter at all since intersection between sets is commutative?   $P_1 (X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2) = P_2 (X_2=x_2, X_1=x_1) = P(\{\omega\mid X_1(\omega) = x_1\} \cap\{\omega \mid X_2(\omega) = x_2\})$

Comment: The order doesn't matter. Did someone tell you it does?

Comment: There is only one probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$. So you should write $P (X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2)$ and leave out the indexes on $P$. Yes, both rvs induces probability measures $P_1,P_2$ on $\mathbb R$ but that is a different story. We have e.g. $P_1(\{x\})=P (X_1=x)$.

Comment: It might be that my interpretation is wrong and you really meant two probability measures on $\Omega$. See for yourself.

Comment: The wording of the question seems a little odd. Can you reproduce the _exact_ wording? Are the distributions supposed to be over ordered pairs? After all, $(1,2)$ is different from $(2,1).$

Comment: @DavidK from your comment i am in the way of getting answer

Comment: @MichaelHardy The link i provided is saying so///

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614629/notation-used-for-multivariate-random-variables

Comment: @hanugm : If you mean the Wikipedia article on exchangeability, where does that article say anything like that? The article in effect contrasts things like $\Pr(X=2\ \&\ Y=20)$ with $\Pr(Y=2\ \&\ X=20)$, but that's quite different from saying that $\Pr(X=2\ \&\ Y=20)$ differs from $\Pr(Y=20\ \&\ X=2). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting explicitly that you are asking for an explanation of statements made [on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables).

The discussion on that page mentions a possibly infinite number of random variables, but even if we consider only the case where there are only two random variables, is not merely about the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, it is about the *sequence* of random variables $(X_1,X_2).$

For $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be exchangeable, the condition is not that
$P_1 (X_1=a, X_2=b) = P_2 (X_2=b, X_1=a).$
The condition is that $P(X_1=a, X_2=b) = P(X_2=a, X_1=b)$:
**one** probability measure (not two), swapping the values of
the variables.

For example, consider the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with support on the set ${1,2}$ such that
\begin{align}
P(X_1=1,X_2=1) &= \frac13,\\
P(X_1=1,X_2=2) &= \frac13,\\
P(X_1=2,X_2=2) &= \frac13.\\
\end{align}

Then
$$ P((X_1,X_2) = (1,2)) = \frac13 \neq 0 = P((X_2,X_1) = (1,2)) $$
and therefore the variables are not exchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

In view of comments posted under the question it seems this may be only a case of misunderstanding something in the linked Wikipedia article.
\begin{align}
\text{These differ from each other: } & \begin{cases} \Pr(X_1=x_1\ \&\ X_2=x_2) \\ \Pr(X_1=x_2\ \&\ X_2=x_1) \end{cases} \\[12pt]
\text{These do not differ from each other: } & \begin{cases} \Pr(X_1=x_1\ \&\ X_2=x_2) \\ \Pr(X_2=x_2\ \&\ X_1=x_1) \end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two different probability measures here. $P_1 (X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2)=P_2 (X_2=x_2, X_1=x_1)$ means $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same joint distribution under the measures $P_1$ and $P_2$.